# C Binary File Reading Buffer Decleration Location Difference

Tags: c, pointers, input, binary, output

Hi everyone I am new for C programming and this is my first question, I try to reading binary file in C code, but solution is change when buffer decleration location is changed as commented rows . Why this situation happen?

```
int main() {
    char *ch;
    //unsigned char *buffer;
    char buffer[129];
    //char *buffer;
    int counter=0;
    FILE *filee;
    int x;
    int i=0;
    filee = fopen("testfile.mtx" , "rb");
    int counter2 = 0;

    while(1) {
        ch = fgetc(filee);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        else
          counter ++ ;
    }
    printf("COUNTER : %d\n",counter);
    //buffer = malloc ((sizeof(char) * counter) +1) ;
    //unsigned char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (counter+1));
    //char buffer[counter];
    fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,filee);
    if(filee== NULL) {
        printf("Fİle cannot opened\n");
    }

    for(i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        printf("%u ", buffer[i]);
        counter2++;
        if(counter2 % 8 == 0 ) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(filee);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char buffer[129];` has a size of 129 bytes, where as `char * buffer` has a size of 4 or 8 depending on the system's bit width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to this line:

```
fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,filee);
```

Here you use `sizeof(buffer)` to calculate the number of bytes to read.

When you use

```
char buffer[129];
```

you'll get `sizeof(buffer)` to be 129.

When you use

```
char *buffer;
buffer = malloc....
```

you'll get `sizeof(buffer)` to be the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8).

Consequently, you read a different number of bytes in the two cases.

You probably want to do:

```
    fread(buffer, counter, 1, filee);
```

BTW:

1) You need to go back to the start of the input file before `fread`

2) The variable `dosya` is undeclared